# Principal Ideal Avoidance

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit. Is it true that given an ideal $I$ and $r \geq 2$ principal ideals $P_1, ..., P_r$, then if $I \subseteq \bigcup_{i = 1}^r P_i$, $I \subseteq P_i$ for some $i$?
This would be the analogous of the Prime Avoidance Lemma for principal ideals.

Comment: As Eric Wofsey has cleverly remarked in his answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555547/counterexamples-to-the-avoidance-lemma-for-arbitrary-ideals), this would imply that all finite rings are principal rings, [which is not the case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071886/example-of-finite-ring-with-a-non-principal-ideal).